# gluLookAt doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl

i'm programming with opengl and i want to change the camera view:

...

```
void RenderScene() //Zeichenfunktion
{

 glClearColor( 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0 );
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT ); 
   glLoadIdentity ();  


    //1.Form:
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );  //polygone

    glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );  //rot
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 ); //unten links   3 =3 koords, f=float


    glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ); //blau 
    glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 ); //unten rechts
    glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );//oben rechts
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );//oben links
    glEnd();



    Wuerfel(0.7);   //creates cube with length 0.7

    gluLookAt ( 0., 0.3, 1.0, 0., 0.7, 0., 0., 1., 0.);




   glFlush(); //Buffer leeren   
}
```

...

when i change the parameter of gluLookAt, nothing happens, what do i wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gluLookAt modifies the current transform matrix, so it only has effect on things rendered after the call. Try putting gluLookAt before your rendering code.